# Password reset confirm/Password reset request-Django Rest api

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to make reset password functionality.I am able to make the password reset request as I receive the user email for which password need to be changed and successfully send the user the email to reset it(via postman).The problem is when I open the reset mail it directs to the password reset confirm where the user enter the new password  to replace the old it in the database.I am unable to handle it with both the GET and POST methods.GET is to display the field where user can enter the new password and POST for posting the request and updating the custom user model.

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

from .models import CustomUser


class SignUpUserSerialzer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, write_only=True)

    def validate_password(self, password):
        return make_password(password)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = '__all__'

class ChangePasswordSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    model = CustomUser

    """
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, write_only=True)

    def validate_password(self, password):
        return make_password(password)
    
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['password']
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
# from .views import ChangePasswordView
urlpatterns = [
   path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
   path('login/', views.custom_login, name='login'),
   path('logout/', views.custom_logout, name='logout'),
   path('user/', views.user_profile, name='user_profile'),
   path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>', views.activate, name='activate'),
   path("passwordreset/", views.password_reset_request, name="password_reset"),
   path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.passwordResetConfirm, name='password_reset_confirm'),

]
```

models..py

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

```
email = models.EmailField(unique=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def register(request):
    # if request.method == "POST":
        # form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    userser = SignUpUserSerialzer(data=request.data)
    print('hello0')
    if userser.is_valid():
        print('hello1')
        user = userser.save(is_active = False)
        print('hello2')
        activateEmail(request, user, userser.validated_data['email'])
        print('hello3')
        return Response(userser.data)

    else:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)


@api_view(['POST'])
def custom_login(request):
    # if request.user.is_authenticated:
    #     return redirect(reverse('home'))

    username=request.data['username']
    password=request.data['password']
    print(username)
    print(password)
    print('login1')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    print('login2')
    print(user)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return Response({"user": user.id})

    else:
        return Response("error")

@api_view(['POST'])
def custom_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return Response("logged out")


def activateEmail(request, user, to_email):
    mail_subject = 'Activate your user account.'
    message = render_to_string('template_activate_account.html', {
        'user': user.username,
        'domain': get_current_site(request).domain,
        'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
        'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
        'protocol': 'https' if request.is_secure() else 'http'
    })
    email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
    if email.send():
        messages.success(request, f'Dear <b>{user}</b>, please go to you email <b>{to_email}</b> inbox and click on \
            received activation link to confirm and complete the registration. <b>Note:</b> Check your spam folder.')
    else:
        messages.error(request,
            f'Problem sending confirmation email to {to_email}, check if you typed it correctly.')

@api_view(['GET'])
def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    User = get_user_model()
    try:
        uid = force_str(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        return Response('account activated')
    else:
        return Response('activation failed')

@api_view(['GET'])
def user_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    posts = Posts.objects.filter(user=user)
    serial = PostsSerializer(posts,many=True)

    return Response(serial.data)



@api_view(['POST'])
def password_reset_request(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            print("pass1")
        # form = PasswordResetForm(request.POST)
        # if form.is_valid():
            user_email = request.data['email']
            print("pass2")
            
            associated_user = get_user_model().objects.filter(Q(email=user_email)).first()
            print("pass3")

            if associated_user:
                subject = "Password Reset request"
                message = render_to_string("template_reset_password.html", {
                    'user': associated_user,
                    'domain': get_current_site(request).domain,
                    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(associated_user.pk)),
                    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(associated_user),
                    "protocol": 'https' if request.is_secure() else 'http'
                })
                email = EmailMessage(subject, message, to=[associated_user.email])
                print("pass4")
                if email.send():
                    messages.success(request,
                        """
                        <h2>Password reset sent</h2><hr>
                        <p>
                            We've emailed you instructions for setting your password, if an account exists with the email you entered. 
                            You should receive them shortly.<br>If you don't receive an email, please make sure you've entered the address 
                            you registered with, and check your spam folder.
                        </p>
                        """
                    )
                    print("pass5")
                    return Response("Password reset sent")
                else:
                    return Response("reset sent")

@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def passwordResetConfirm(request, uidb64, token):
    User = get_user_model()
    try:
        uid = force_str(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
        print("confr0")
    except:
        user = None
    print("confr1")
    print(user)

    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        print("enter1")
        if request.method == 'POST':
            passser = ChangePasswordSerializer(data=request.data)
            print("enter2")

            # form = SetPasswordForm(user, request.POST)
            # password=request.data['password']
            if passser.is_valid():
                print('passre1')
                passw = passser.save()
                print('passre2')
                # form.save()
                return Response("pass succefuly changed")
            else:
                return Response("error")
        else:
            passser = ChangePasswordSerializer()  
            return Response(passser.data)  

    else:
        return Response(" major error")
```

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):


    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Answer (score 3):

1. you didn't read the documentation of DRF, Here is the link of DRF
   https://www.django-rest-framework.org
2. `request.data` returns the parsed content of the `request body`. This is similar to the standard `request.POST` and `request.FILES` attributes. You can check here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/
3. **Rest Framework** provides an Api View, which subclasses Django's View class. Here is the link https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/
4. The `Generic views` provided by REST framework allow you to quickly build API views that map closely to your database models. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/
5. A ViewSet class is simply a type of class-based View, that does not provide any method handlers such as .get() or .post(), and instead provides actions such as .list() and .create(). https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

**Important**: you didn't call the `serializer.save()` that's why the user not saved in database.

if you want to implement Password Reset in Rest API: Here is the link you can check:  https://github.com/tanveer-ahmad74/Dummy